# How to toggle Effect in Div using only css?

Tags: html, css, toggle

I tried all questions & answers related this topic. Additionally  and I tried related questions and try to solve it but not success. So please  read my question deathly.

**I Want to**

1. I `click me` Div then Second `hiddendiv` Div display. But I want to click a second time in `click me` Div,  then hide a `hiddendiv` Div . **Similar toggle event**  using pure css.
2. I `click me` Div then Second `hiddendiv` Div display.  But I click other area click then hide a`hiddendiv` Div . So I want to not hide a`hiddendiv` Div in any other click using pure css.

> Only  pure CSS,CSS3 Use in Answer not use (**javascript,jquery**) &
> any other from control

**Code**

```css
.clicker {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#FFF;
}

.hiddendiv {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.clicker:focus+.hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me</div>
  <div class="hiddendiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not possible with the given requirements

Comment: I did post an answer, which is the closest workaround, CSS only and no form controls

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is not possible with the given requirements, all elements being a `div`.

It would be possible if you change `div`'s acting as links to anchors `a`, and use `:target` pseudo

By setting `display: inline-block` on the anchor `a`, you can size it as you can with a `div`

```css
.clicker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color:#FFF;
}
.clicker.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hiddendiv {
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.hiddendiv.nr2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#showdiv1:target ~ div a[href="#showdiv1"],
#showdiv2:target ~ div a[href="#showdiv2"] {
  display: none;
}
#showdiv1:target ~ div a[href="#hidediv1"],
#showdiv2:target ~ div a[href="#hidediv2"] {
  display: inline-block;
}
#showdiv1:target ~ div .hiddendiv.nr1,
#showdiv2:target ~ div .hiddendiv.nr2 {
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div id="showdiv1"></div>
<div id="showdiv2"></div>

<div>
  <a href="#showdiv1" class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="#hidediv1" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>

  <a href="#showdiv2" class="clicker" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="#hidediv2" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>

  <div class="hiddendiv nr1"></div>
  <div class="hiddendiv nr2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank for answer . but can you help you div show display smoothly. using transition .

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `checkbox` input and based on if this is checked or not you can show hide the div.

below is a example using the same.

```css
.clicker {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#FFF;
  display:block;
}

.hiddendiv {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.clicker:focus+.hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
.hidden{
  margin-left:-99999px;
}
input#cmn-toggle-7:checked + label + div{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="cmn-toggle-7" class="hidden" type="checkbox" >
  <label for="cmn-toggle-7" class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me</label>
  <div class="hiddendiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer . but not use checkbox . only div event toggle without any from control.

Answer (score 6):

you achieve that using checkbox with some css manipulation

```css
div input {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.check-btn label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.check-btn input {
  display: none;
}

.clicker {
  background: green;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.hiddendiv {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.check-btn input:checked ~ .hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-btn">

    <input id="myid" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="myid" class="clicker">Click me</label>
    <div class="hiddendiv"></div>

</div>
```

[**Here jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/codename0/pmufnvk2/)

Comment: thanks for answer. but i click black div then hide black div this is not true