# How to Toogle in Css?

Tags: html, css

I got a task to create a modified selector, then I found an example that I can then apply to my view, but something strange and I have tried it but did not succeed to make toogle from the list.

here's my html syntax:

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">State</label>
        <div class="select-box__current" onclick="toogle" tabindex="1">
            <div class="form-check  select-box__value">
                <input 
                        class   = "select-box__input"
                        type    = "radio"
                        name    = "exampleRadios"
                        id      = "1"
                        value   = "1"
                        checked = "checked">
                    <label class   = "form-check-label select-box__input-text" for = "exampleRadios1">
                    Cream
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check select-box__value">
                <input 
                        class   = "select-box__input"
                        type    = "radio"
                        name    = "exampleRadios"
                        id      = "2"
                        value   = "2">
                    <label class   = "form-check-label select-box__input-text" for = "exampleRadios2">
                    Cheese
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check select-box__value">
                <input 
                        class   = "select-box__input"
                        type    = "radio"
                        name    = "exampleRadios"
                        id      = "3"
                        value   = "3">
                    <label class   = "form-check-label select-box__input-text" for = "exampleRadios2">
                    Toast
                </label>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg select-box__icon"></i>
        </div>

        <ul class="select-box__list">
            <li>
                <label class="select-box__option" for="1" aria-hidden="aria-hidden"
                    >Cream</label
                >
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="select-box__option" for="2" aria-hidden="aria-hidden"
                    >Cheese</label
                >
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="select-box__option" for="3" aria-hidden="aria-hidden"
                    >Toast</label
                >
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

and here's my css:

```
.select-box__current{
    position  : relative;
    cursor    : pointer;
    outline   : none;
}

.select-box__current:focus + .select-box__list {
    opacity               : 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: none;
    animation-name        : none;
    position              : absolute;
}

.select-box__current:focus + .select-box__list .select-box__option {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box__value {
    display      : -webkit-box;
    display      : flex;
}

.select-box__input {
    display: none;
}

.select-box__current:not(:focus) + .select-box__list {
    position: absolute;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .select-box__current:focus + .select-box__list{
        position: relative;
    }
}

.select-box__input:checked + .select-box__input-text {
    display: flex;
}

.select-box__input-text {
    display         : none;
    width           : 100%;
    margin          : 0;
    padding         : 15px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #ffdada );
    border-radius   : 15px;
}

.select-box__list {
    position                         : inherit;
    display                          : block;
    margin-top                       : 1rem;
    width                            : 100%;
    padding                          : 0;
    list-style                       : none;
    opacity                          : 0;
    -webkit-animation-name           : HideList;
    animation-name                   : HideList;
    -webkit-animation-duration       : 0.5s;
    animation-duration               : 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay          : 0.5s;
    animation-delay                  : 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode      : forwards;
    animation-fill-mode              : forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: step-start;
    animation-timing-function        : step-start;
}

.select-box__option {
    display      : block;
    padding      : 15px;
    background   : #ffc7c7;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.select-box__option:hover, .select-box__option:focus {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #ffdada );
    box-shadow      : 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: magenta;
}

/* chevron logo */
.select-box__current:focus .select-box__icon {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
            transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    /* -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1); */
}
.select-box__icon {
    position          : absolute;
    top               : 50%;
    right             : 15px;
    transform         : translateY(-50%);
    opacity           : 0.3;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease;
    transition        : 0.2s ease;
}

.form-check-label.select-box__input-text{
    padding-left: 25px;
}
label.select-box__option{
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.border-right-radius{
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    border       : 1px solid #ffe2e4;
    background   : #ffdada;
}

@-webkit-keyframes HideList {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
                transform: scaleY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes HideList {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
                transform: scaleY(0);
    }
}
```

For your information, i have got the code from [here](https://codepen.io/miniven/pen/ZJydge)
thank you for taking the time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to toggle Effect in Div using only css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267467/how-to-toggle-effect-in-div-using-only-css)

Comment: Maybe this could interest you : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_details

Comment: yaa..true, i searched like that but could not find the right keywords @Elharony