# Change multiple element's style with css only

Tags: html, css, background-color

I need to change multiple element's background color in a table, but I am not allowed to use javascript.

At first I've implemented a code to see the result I need, this time using javascript.
The code works, but as I said I need to implement something with NO javascript. CSS only.

As you can see, I have a few rows in a table, and once clicked upon cells 1 or 2 the proper row assumes a certain color pattern. Such pattern applies to all rows in my table (there will be 12 rows in the final implementation).

I've found a solution for a single element, which I show in the **div** element, but it applies to one element only. I can't figure it out how to change all the td's in a row, with the color patter I need.

By the way, in each row there will be 35 cells. It won't be just 5, like in this example.

```js
document.getElementById("td_1_0").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.getElementById("td_1_1").classList.toggle("cRed");
    document.getElementById("td_1_2").classList.toggle("cYellow");
    document.getElementById("td_1_3").classList.toggle("cRed");
    document.getElementById("td_1_4").classList.toggle("cLime");
    document.getElementById("td_1_5").classList.toggle("cLime");
});
document.getElementById("td_2_0").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.getElementById("td_2_1").classList.toggle("cRed");
    document.getElementById("td_2_2").classList.toggle("cYellow");
    document.getElementById("td_2_3").classList.toggle("cRed");
    document.getElementById("td_2_4").classList.toggle("cLime");
    document.getElementById("td_2_5").classList.toggle("cLime");
});
```

```css
html {
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.cRed {
    background-color: red;
}
.cLime {
    background-color: lime;
}
.cYellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
div {
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 200px;
}
input:checked + div { background-color: cyan;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td_1_0">1</td>
        <td id="td_1_1">A</td>
        <td id="td_1_2">B</td>
        <td id="td_1_3">C</td>
        <td id="td_1_4">D</td>
        <td id="td_1_5">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td_2_0">2</td>
        <td id="td_2_1">F</td>
        <td id="td_2_2">G</td>
        <td id="td_2_3">H</td>
        <td id="td_2_4">I</td>
        <td id="td_2_5">J</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" hidden>
    <div>click to change (div)</div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying this is a great idea, but it does what you're trying to do, without any javascript. It uses the same checkbox hack as your example div.

1. Add a checkbox for each row, immediately before the table.
2. Stick a label for the appropriate checkbox in the corresponding row. (This allows clicking the cell to toggle the checkbox.)
3. Position the label absolutely so the click area covers the entire cell.
4. Use a bunch of clunky sibling and nth-child selectors to target the appropriate cells and change their color.

This obviously isn't ideal, but it's workable for a relatively small table if you have no other options.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    position: relative;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

#row1:checked ~ table tr:first-child :nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

#row1:checked ~ table tr:first-child :nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

#row1:checked ~ table tr:first-child :nth-child(4) {
  background: red;
}

#row1:checked ~ table tr:first-child :nth-child(5) {
  background: green;
}

#row1:checked ~ table tr:first-child :nth-child(6) {
  background: green;
}


#row2:checked ~ table tr:nth-child(2) :nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

#row2:checked ~ table tr:nth-child(2) :nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

#row2:checked ~ table tr:nth-child(2) :nth-child(4) {
  background: red;
}

#row2:checked ~ table tr:nth-child(2) :nth-child(5) {
  background: green;
}

#row2:checked ~ table tr:nth-child(2) :nth-child(6) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="row1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="row2" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="row1"></label>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr tabIndex="0">
    <td><label for="row2"></label>2</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did all those eventlisteners programmatically, i.e. in a "for loop". As I said, there will be 12 rows, with 35 cells each. It was not a problem to set up 420 eventlisteners (12 x 35) with a loop, but it will be a different story to do it cell by cell with this solution you gave me... I guess it will do the job, but I was hoping there would be a simpler solution, cause the pattern is the same for all the rows.

Comment: You could reduce the amount of css you’d need by having the cells colored by default, then using a more general selector to set unchecked row td’s to a white background, but it’s still a bit ugly.

Comment: I'm gonna stick to this solution. I made all cells colored by default, and now when I click in the "control cell" the entire row turns white (or lightgray, it's alternate). This solve my problem, but it would be better NOT to have them all colored at start... but it's ok. It works. Would it be so difficult to have the entire row clickable?... Because the action happens by clicking in the LABEL tag, which is the first TD only. A label for all cells maybe?... Or a better solution?... Thank you very much!

Comment: If you moved `position: relative` from the td to the tr, the label would span the entire row, making the whole thing clickable.

Comment: Actually I'm not using that line. The whole thing is a calendar (with 35 cells per month), so the left cell is the month's name. It's a fixed cell, so the calendar scrolls left, keeping the month's name always visible.

Comment: Okay. Hard to say for sure without seeing it, but if you _did_ make the tr position relative and the label position absolute with inset 0, it should span the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

If you can influence table construction at the backend then try something like this:

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
}

input:checked~.cRed {
  background-color: red;
}

input:checked~.cLime {
  background-color: lime;
}

input:checked~.cYellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.cell:first-child {
  visibility: collapse;
  width: 1%;
}

.cell:not(.clickable) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <label for="1" class="row">
      <input id="1" class="cell" type="checkbox" hidden>
      <div class="cell clickable">1</div>
      <div class="cell cRed">A</div>
      <div class="cell cYellow">B</div>
      <div class="cell cRed">C</div>
      <div class="cell cLime">D</div>
      <div class="cell cLime">E</div>
    </label>
  <label for="2" class="row">
      <input id="2" class="cell" type="checkbox" hidden>
      <div class="cell clickable">2</div>
      <div class="cell cRed">A</div>
      <div class="cell cYellow">B</div>
      <div class="cell cRed">C</div>
      <div class="cell cLime">D</div>
      <div class="cell cLime">E</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Whatever solution you'll get you'll have to set at least color classes on each table cell. This way if backend decides to change colors then it'll happen automatically.
But if you want to set the pattern at CSS side then you can use `input:checked~:nth-child(3 ... 36)` instead of using `input:checked~.cRed`.  This way it'll repeat for all 12 rows automatically:

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
}

input:checked~:nth-child(3),
input:checked~:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: red;
}

input:checked~:nth-child(6),
input:checked~:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: lime;
}

input:checked~:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.cell:first-child {
  visibility: collapse;
  width: 1%;
}

.cell:not(.clickable) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <label for="1" class="row">
      <input id="1" class="cell" type="checkbox" hidden>
      <div class="cell clickable">1</div>
      <div class="cell">A</div>
      <div class="cell">B</div>
      <div class="cell">C</div>
      <div class="cell">D</div>
      <div class="cell">E</div>
    </label>
  <label for="2" class="row">
      <input id="2" class="cell" type="checkbox" hidden>
      <div class="cell clickable">2</div>
      <div class="cell">A</div>
      <div class="cell">B</div>
      <div class="cell">C</div>
      <div class="cell">D</div>
      <div class="cell">E</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

---

Other way is using anchor tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269449/15273968

It's a same approach as using siblings selector. But you'll have to create 2 anchor tags for each of 12 rows.

---

**Edit:** You can achieve CSS only scroll beneath:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    input:checked~:nth-child(3),
    input:checked~:nth-child(5) {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    input:checked~:nth-child(6),
    input:checked~:nth-child(7) {
      background-color: lime;
    }
    
    input:checked~:nth-child(4) {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .table {
      display: table;
      width: 700px;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: table-row;
    }
    
    .cell {
      display: table-cell;
      left: 0;
      border: 1px black solid;
    }
    
    .cell:not(.clickable) {
      pointer-events: none;
      z-index: -100;
    }
    
    .cell:first-child {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .clickable {
      background-color: white;
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      width: 2rem;
      z-index: 100;
      background-color: wheat;
    }
    
    .container {
      height: 100px;
      width: 400px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=container>
    <div class="table">
      <label for="1" class="row">
        <input id="1" class="cell" type="checkbox" hidden>
        <div class="cell clickable">1</div>
        <div class="cell">A</div>
        <div class="cell">B</div>
        <div class="cell">C</div>
        <div class="cell">D</div>
        <div class="cell">E</div>
      </label>
      <label for="2" class="row">
        <input id="2" class="cell" type="checkbox" hidden>
        <div class="cell clickable">2</div>
        <div class="cell">A</div>
        <div class="cell">B</div>
        <div class="cell">C</div>
        <div class="cell">D</div>
        <div class="cell">E</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes?... I mean, I almost said "YES!!!", cause it really achieves what I want, aesthetically wise. My only concern is about the table construction... By now (with my javascript solution) I have a table with the left cells fixed (the clickable ones, the control cells), so the table rolls to the left and the cells disapears beneath the control cells (cause in a cell phone I can't show 35 cells all at once, so I need to make it scroll, but keeping the control cells fixed). Of course this is css, but I wonder if there will be any trouble if I change the table construction from table tags to divs.

Comment: With `display: table-cell;` the divs should exactly behave like normal table cells. I think there shouldn't be any problem. You'll have to remove `table`, `row`, `td` such specific tag queries from JS.

Comment: You can achieve css only scroll beneath without javascript. Unless you are doing more complex stuff you can try the new solution in the answer.

Comment: Yes, the scrolling part is all css. But I'm still struggling to make it work with this new approach (div instead of table). My original table has tds with min-height: 40px set, but it's not working with the divs (they are all with 20px, no idea why...). I put an outer div, under the label tag, and tried ".cell:nth-child(2) {position: fixed; left: 0;}", but at this point only the clickable div assumed the min-height:40px, and all the other remained with 20px,.

Comment: You need to set min-height on child of the div. `<div class="cell"><div style="min-height: 40px;">A</div></div>`

Comment: You mean, I have to put a div inside those class "cell" divs?... Like you just you did? I tried to set min-height as attibute for the "cell" class alone, but didn't work. Min-width works, so why min-height doesn't?...

Comment: You can’t give percentage heights to all elements.Based on what number the percentages will be evaluated? at least one element in the hierarchy has to have fixed `height`. In cell you are not going to have just text so it’s better to put one more div with min-height set.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I tried the other solution, using table, and it gave me less trouble... In my tests I realized that using div I could get the entire row to be clickable, which is better for the user, but I'm struggling with this height problem and there would be more stuff coming. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I tried to accept both answers, but it was not possible... sorry...